# Django: Complex annotate/prefetch query

Tags: django

Suppose I have the following Django models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Payment(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have various accounts and various people can make payments into the account. I want to display a list of accounts and show who made the last payment, what was the amount and date. Something like this (not sure how to add a proper table here):

Account | Last payment made by | Date of last payment

Food    | Peter                | 3 Feb 2018

Drinks  | John                 | 10 Feb 2018

How can I achieve this with a single or two queries? Maybe through some fancy prefetch/annotate but I can't figure it out. I can get the last date by using a annotate + max, but how will I get the person that made the payment?

Otherwise I'll just have to query each row. If I limit the number of account to 50, then I guess 50 queries isn't that bad, but still not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Payment` ID is sequential and it always match the date field, in a sense that latest payment always get the most recent ID, you could do it with two queries:

```
from django.db.models import Max

last_payments_ids = Payment.objects \
    .values('account_id') \
    .annotate(last_payment_id=Max('id')) \
    .values_list('last_payment_id', flat=True)

last_payment_per_account = Payment.objects \
    .select_related('account', 'person') \
    .filter(id__in=last_payments_ids)
```

Note that I'm using the `account_id` to create a group by expression, and then the `Max('id')` is applied to the id of the `Payment`, and not the `Account`.

Just two queries, no matter how many records:

```
{% for payment in last_payment_per_account %}
    <td>{{ payment.account.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ payment.person.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ payment.date }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but IDs won't necessarily be in order. What about a max on the date?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many records you're dealing with (eg unless it's millions) then I don't think any annotation or custom SQL is needed:

```
recent_payments = Payment.objects.order_by('-date').select_related("account")
```

or if you want last payment object you can fetch by `latest()`

```
recent_payments = Payment.objects.order_by('-date').latest().select_related("account")
```

Then just fly through the results:

```
for payment in recent_payments:
  col1 = payment.account.name  # eg "Food"
  col2 = payment.person.first_name  # eg "John"
  col3 = payment.date.strftime("-%d %B %Y")  # eg "10 Feb 2018"
```

Remember to add db_index=True to the date field because you'd be sorting on that field, and sorts are MUCH slower on unindexed fields.

EDIT: Apologies, I misread the initial question to think that it was a record of ALL payments. The above answer does an elegant job of doing what OP originally requested.

Comment: I think what he wants is to get only the *last* `Payment` per `Account`. So, if in the database there are 5 accounts, and 1000 payments (and considering that all the accounts received at least 1 payment), the queryset should return 5 rows only

Comment: @VitorFreitas That's correct. I think it might work if you query account and prefetch all the payments, but only use the latest one

Comment: updated accordingly :) 
this approach is less database intensive bdw.

Comment: The [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest) return a single object, so it will return a `Payment` instance, instead of a `QuerySet<Payment>`